# Terminal input treated different when programm is executed by gradle

Tags: linux, gradle, terminal, system.in, gradle-task

When I execute a simple programm in the linux terminal, everything works as exspected.
Example with python3:

```
print('input value')
value = input()
print('your value', value)
```

When this script is executed by gradle, the behavior is different:

Example gradle task:

```
task (testInput, type:Exec){
 standardInput = System.in
 commandLine 'python', 'test.py'
}
```

E.g. when the arrows are pressed, this happens:

```
input value
^[[A^[[D^[[C^[[A^[[D^[[C^[[A^[[D^[[D^[[A^[[C^[[D^[[C^[[D^[[A^[[C^[[D
```

Why? How can I switch this off?